# CASE statement in the WHERE clause, with further conditioning after THEN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of invoices and one of contracts that invoices are linked to. However, not every invoice is linked to a contract. I want to return all invoices linked to contracts which are within a timeframe (Starting before 2021-03-01), and also the invoices with no contracts linked at all. I believe this is something like: contract IS null OR CASE WHEN contract IS NOT NULL THEN (condition on timestamp), but I don't know how to write it. Note that the actual conditioning will be done on multiple columns, so I am looking for the general form of multiple sub-conditions under the conditions in the WHERE clause.

Example:

Invoice Table

| InvoiceID | ContractID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | NULL |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |

Contract Table

| ContractID | Contract Start Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2021-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 |

Desired Result

| InvoiceID | ContractID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | NULL |
| 4 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe a simple left join like this can help you in filtering

```
select 
I.*
from Invoice I
left outer join Contract C -- left join gets even the NULL contractid invoices
on C.ContractID= I.ContractID
where 
  C.[Contract Start Timestamp] IS NULL
  OR C.[Contract Start Timestamp]< '2021-03-01'
```

Comment: Nice one, it worked in this case, thank you. But I still want a more general form so I don't post the question again later on. Can't upvote due to low reputation.

Comment: @SamuelHyde what other types of conditions do you have ? you can simply extend WHERE conditions using case as well like `OR CASE WHEN Status IN (2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END =1`

Comment: I have more timestamps on the contracts that I want to check against, for which your solution worked perfectly, but yes, I am hoping for a way to learn about 0 and 1s in the CASE statement, which I know little about. Especially I don't know how OR works to link them

Comment: To read about conditional [OR] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/or-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and about [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)